# Database setup of bridge/integration between scripts

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, mediawiki, vbulletin, forums

If I'm using an integration/bridge script for a cms and forums, more specifically drupal or mediawiki and vbulletin, how should I set up the database?

Should I have one database named "mysite" and place both cms and forum tables into the same database? So have all drupal tables with "drupal_" prefix and all tables with "vb_" prefix in the same database.

Or should I have two databases, one for the main site and one for the forums, and I wouldn't need table prefixes in that case.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each method? Is one way less resource intensive? And is one way just downright better?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say do separate databases if you can.  The only reason to put two products in the same database is if you can only have one from your hosting provider.